# NSManagedObject data is <fault> and entity is null, after UITableViewCell comes back into view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am seeing some very odd behavior with Core Data using Swift and Xcode 7.2. Below is an animation illustrating the issue.

[image: Problem]

I created a simple example with an entity named 'Person' that has only a 'name' attribute. I fetch all of the 'Person' entities and display them in a table view. If I force a cell to be reloaded then the textLabel that holds the name and NSManagedObject objectID displays without the name. The objectID, however, remains unchanged. This happens both on the device and in the simulator.

I'm printing the value of the Person entity to the console in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" so that I can show the value when the cell is initially loaded vs. when it's reloaded.

[image: Person entity value]

As you can see, it appears that the NSManagedObject is still present despite the fact that it seems to lose all references to its 'Person' subclass.

Here is the code for the affected ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  let cellIdentifier = "PersonCell"

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  var people: NSArray = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    people = fetchPeople()
  }

  func fetchPeople() -> NSArray {
    let context = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
      let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
      return results
    } catch {
      let error = error as NSError
      print("\(error.domain) \(error.code): \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return []
    }
  }

  // MARK: - UITableView methods

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    print("in cellForRowAtIndexPath:")
    print(people[0])

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(person.name) - \(person.objectID)"
    return cell
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
let context = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
```

You create a *new instance* of the application delegate, and with it
a managed object context. As soon as program control returns from `fetchPeople()`, there is no reference to the context anymore and it is
deallocated. The effect is that accessing properties of managed objects
which were created in this context returns `nil`.

What you want is to get a reference to *the* (one and only) application delegate
and its managed object context, something like

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Alternatively, pass the context to the view controller in
the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method or in 
`prepareForSegue` or whatever is suitable in your app.

Comment: Thanks you helped me understand a problem I was having :)

Comment: Just understood the cause of 99% of my issues with nil entities and data faults. I was using a custom object, not AppDelegate, but new instances were created all the time. Replaced with a singleton and ev works great now. Thanks!